# qabstractitemmodel data not changing in qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qabstractitemmodel

I have copied the Qt example animal qabstractitemmodel and try to show it in QML and change values. I have added a function to the model to do that

```
Q_INVOKABLE void change()
{
     m_animals.first().m_size="newValue";
     // setData(this->index(0), "newValue", SizeRole); //always returns false, has no effect if uncommented
     qDebug() << this->data(this->index(0), SizeRole); //returns correctly new value as set in previous uncommented line

     emit dataChanged(this->index(0), this->index(this->rowCount()), {SizeRole}); // the value in QML is not updated at any point
}
```

Why is the value not updating in QML?

I have uploaded the complete sample

https://ufile.io/jfflj

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused because the `index(rowCount()`) is a QModelIndex invalid, instead you must use `index(rowCount()- 1)` or better just indicate that row 0 is updated with `index(0)` :

```
Q_INVOKABLE void change()
{
    m_animals.first().m_size="newValue";
    qDebug() << this->data(this->index(0), SizeRole);
    emit dataChanged(index(0), index(rowCount()-1), {SizeRole});
    // or better
    // emit dataChanged(index(0), index(0), {SizeRole});
}
```

On the other hand you point out in the comments that `setData()` always returns false, and that is correct since when using the QAbstractListModel() class as a base you must implement that method:

```
bool AnimalModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if(!index.isValid()) return false;
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= rowCount()) return false;
    Animal & animal =  m_animals[index.row()];
    if(role == TypeRole)
        animal.m_type = value.toString();
    else if(role == SizeRole)
        m_animals[index.row()].m_size = value.toString();
    else
        return false;
    emit dataChanged(index, index, {role});
    return true;
}
```

And then you can use it:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void change()
{
    setData(index(0), "newValue", SizeRole);
}
```